# Keep position: fixed; right: 0; element on screen on mobile browser

Tags: css

On a mobile device, an element with `position: fixed; right: 0;` gets pushed out of the viewport if some other element is wider than the viewport, but not on desktop. Like this:

[image]

How can I ensure that element remains on screen in mobile browsers?

Play with http://jsbin.com/zawijayata/edit?html,output and http://output.jsbin.com/zawijayata/.

Comment: What is this tool you use to test? Did you check if it's a bug of this tool?

Comment: It looks like chrome to me - does it on my chrome too

Comment: Not sure it would happen on a mobile device though, does it? Also doesn't break on FF

Comment: Same thing on mobile Chrome, although I can zoom out.

Comment: `vw` units seem to behave like I want, so `position: fixed; left:calc(100vw - 75px);` sort of works, but I'd rather leave the hard-coded 75px out of there. Can I use `100vw` in some clever way to get the result I want? e.g. http://output.jsbin.com/pohovodoxo/

Comment: I've the identical issue. Happens on actual phones, and on desktop browsers when set in F12 > mobile device emulation mode. Surprisingly, the desktop browsers in normal mode, but manually dragged to the same narrow width, behave as expected. I've not found any reference to explain the mobile behaviour. Thank you for the tip on the calc(100vw - 75px) Trevor. Very neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's a reason to have an element bigger than the viewport, Change your `width:400px` on the div below, to:

```
width: 100%;
max-width: 400px;
```

Comment: Good answer but do you know why this happens? I'm curious to know

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately elements on the page sometimes have to be wide.

Comment: This is approximately what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

`vw` units seem to behave like I want, so `position: fixed; left:calc(100vw - 75px);` sort of works, but it requires hard coding the width of the element (75px). Maybe there's another way to use `vw` to get the right effect.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution - position: absolute instead of fixed works, I've pasted the code into a page and hosted on a local environment to test on an actual mobile device and it works (though it didn't work in your codebin, don't know why).
Also note the change to the meta viewport line so mobile browsers don't try to shrink the page down to fit the 600px div in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0;">Top Right</div>
    <div style="width:600px; border:1px solid blue;">600px<?
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "left:calc(100vw - 75px)" sort-of worked but caused other issues for me. Luckily found another way to solve this on mobile browsers.

Adding display: fixed and overflow: auto on the outside div made the problem go away.

This was in addition to the position: fixed; right: 0; on the inner element. I did have position:absolute on the outer div previously. That was implemented as a modal, with display:none by default.